# Trait specialization of templated type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, traits

I have a trait to return some information about a class e.g. the number of dimensions:

```
template< typename T >
struct NumDims;
```

For a "normal" class this is easy to specialize:

```
template<>
struct NumDims< MyClass >: std::integral_constant< unsigned, 3 >{};
```

But I have some heavy templated classes that all have a common static constexpr like:

```
template< class T, class U, class V, bool x, bool y, bool z >
struct TemplateClass{
    static constexpr unsigned numDims = ...;
}
```

A specilization looks ugly and errorprone:

```
template< class T, class U, class V, bool x, bool y, bool z >
struct NumDims< TemplateClass<T,U,V,x,y,z> >{
    static constexpr unsigned value = TemplateClass<T,U,V,x,y,z>::numDims;
}
```

I tried to use variadic templates:

```
template< class... T >
struct NumDims< TemplateClass<T...> >{
    static constexpr unsigned value = TemplateClass<T...>::numDims;
}
```

But this crashes my compiler (gcc 4.8.2):
    *internal compiler error: in unify_one_argument, at cp/pt.c:15506*

Any ideas to do this "the prober" way?

Comment: Do you want a trait to have `static constexpr unsigned numDims` if it exists ?

Comment: `constexpr` function support in your compiler?

Comment: `class... T` won't match the `bool`s anyway.

Comment: Error added to question
@Jarod42: Not only. Although that would help in this case. But I also have "policies" that are of the same form, but take a reference to the object in the ()-operator and return a member of that object

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that you have a mixture of type and non-type parameters in your `TemplateClass` class template, so you can't have a variadic type parameter. As far as I know, there is currently no way to mix type and non-type arguments like that, short of wrapping the non-type ones in some dummy template.

Fortunately, you can side-step the whole issue and just have a partial specialization which is enabled when the type you pass in has a `numDims` static member:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct NumDims;

template<>
struct NumDims< MyClass >: std::integral_constant< unsigned, 3 >{};

template< class T >
struct NumDims< T, void_t<decltype(T::numDims)> >{
    static constexpr unsigned value = T::numDims;
};
```

This uses `void_t` which is not yet standard, so you can use a simple implementation like this:

```
template <typename...>
struct voider { using type = void; };
template <typename... Ts> using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;
```

Comment: This DOES solve it in quite some cases. But not all. Consider a heavy templated type that represents a 3D-array: NumDims should be 3 for all cases.

Comment: In that case I think you'd need to wrap the heavy templated type to change all the non-type parameters into types, like `integral_constant`.